# Migrate data from MySQL master database to HDFS

Tags: hadoop

Assume there is no slave database. It's very high risk to directly use sqoop to transmit data from master database to HDFS.

So is there any solution to deal with this case?

Comment: Why is it high risk?

Comment: @HakkiBuyukcengiz For instance, such buck data migration may get important tables locked.

Comment: You can throttle the parallelization of the sqoop job. The "-m" option sets the mapper count.

Comment: @HakkiBuyukcengiz Thanks for your reply man. I thought about that but if data amount is too large, this may take too much time to migrate.

Comment: So this is not the sqoop's issue. Maybe you can backup the master database just before the migration process.